# Adding a container to an existing docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've got a simple `docker-compose.yml` with 3 services: *Grafana*, *Telegraf* and *InfluxDB* - it all works as expected.

Couple days later I had to add another container: *Grafana Image Renderer*. I have added it to the `docker-compose.yml` file and can start it with `docker-compose start renderer`. However unlike the first 3 containers it doesn't auto-start after the instance reboot. All 4 containers have the same config including `restart: always`.

Is there any way to **update docker-compose with the new config** so that the *Renderer* container behaves the same as the other three without having to do `docker-compose down` and `up` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to stop the other containers, `docker-compose up` will create/recreate new/updated containers and take in account the restart policy, no need to do `docker-compose down`.

Comment: Ah, I didn’t know I could `up` an already-up stack. Thanks!